# Recycler view does not refresh on filter - ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I have an edit text and a recycler view, what I intend of the edit text is to use the input as a filter on the list. Here is my code:

Fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_trains_view, container, false);

        mountain.customwidgets.MontserratRegularAutoComplete editStationSearch =
                (mountain.customwidgets.MontserratRegularAutoComplete)
                        view.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteSource);

        editStationSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);

            }
        });


        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        CsvReaderImpl csvReader = new CsvReaderImpl();
        stationNameCodePojoArrayList = csvReader.ReadFromfile("data/stations.txt", getActivity());

        mAdapter = new StationsRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),stationNameCodePojoArrayList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
            @Override
            public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
                // Do not draw the divider
            }
        });

        return view;

    }
```

Here is my adapter class:

```
public class StationsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StationsRecyclerAdapter.DataObjectHolder> implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<StationPojo> mDataset;
    private StationTextFilter stationTextFilter;
    private Context ctx;

    public StationsRecyclerAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<StationPojo> myDataset) {
        this.mDataset = (new ArrayList<>(myDataset));
        this.ctx = ctx;
        for (int i = 0; i < mDataset.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("mDatasset Original: " + Arrays.asList(mDataset.get(i).getStationName()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (stationTextFilter == null) {
            stationTextFilter = new StationTextFilter(this, mDataset);
        }
        return stationTextFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.row_auto_complete, parent, false);
        return new DataObjectHolder(mView);
    }

    public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView stationName;
        TextView stationCode;
        TextView stationElevation;


        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            stationName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textStationName);
            stationCode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textStationCode);
            stationElevation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textStationElevation);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.stationCode.setText(mDataset.get(position).getStationCode());
        holder.stationElevation.setText(mDataset.get(position).getStationElevation());
        holder.stationName.setText(mDataset.get(position).getStationName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

}
```

And here is the Filter class:

```
public class StationTextFilter extends Filter {

    private final StationsRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    private List<StationPojo> mDataset;
    private final List<StationPojo> filteredList;

    public StationTextFilter(StationsRecyclerAdapter adapter, List<StationPojo> mDataset) {
        super();
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.mDataset = new ArrayList<>(mDataset);
        this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        filteredList.clear();
        final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (charSequence.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(mDataset);
        } else {
            final String filterPattern = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            for (StationPojo item : mDataset) {
                if (item.getStationName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                    filteredList.add(item);
                    System.out.println("Match found Word: " + filterPattern);

                }
            }
        }

        results.values = filteredList;
        results.count = filteredList.size();
        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        mDataset.clear();
        mDataset.addAll((ArrayList<StationPojo>) filterResults.values);
        for (int i = 0; i < mDataset.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("mDatasset at filter: " + Arrays.asList(mDataset.get(i).getStationName()));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure that things work fine till the `mDataset.addAll((ArrayList<StationPojo>) filterResults.values);` as I can print the filtered results, somehow I am not able to know why notifyDatasetChanged does not work! Any headings?

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) as a base class and override its `matches()` method, something like this: `class A extends MatchableRVArrayAdapter<StationPojo, A.VH> {...`

Comment: I will have to go through the code you posted. Will definitely follow it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `Adapter` is referencing a different `ArrayList` and not the one in your `StationTextFilter`. See here

```
  public StationTextFilter(StationsRecyclerAdapter adapter, List<StationPojo> mDataset) {
        super();
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.mDataset = new ArrayList<>(mDataset);
        this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

The `mDataset` is the actual referenced `ArrayList` in your adapter, but here you are creating an entirely new `ArrayList` and thus does not get reflected in your `notifyDataSetChanged`.

One way to solve this is to not create a new `ArrayList` and use it as it is.

```
this.mDataset = mDataset;
```

Comment: @User3 Does your filter work? Did you check the contents of it?

Comment: Yes it does, I can get the filter! As I mentioned in my original question.

Comment: Buddy, you were right. I made a mistake in reading your answer and thought you suggesting this change in my Adapter class. However I had a closer look and made the change in my TextFilter class and it works good now. Thanks a lot. However now I am not able to restore the original list after back press. New seas!